# TypeError: dropdown is null when trying to access Dom element in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

please am  having this error  in react , okay  imported  some external  js file  , that  where doing some  kind  of  Dom manipulations like adding css class and removing css class from my template .  The problem  is that when my class  App.js  loads  it gives  me  an   error that  the drop down class is not found  , from my own understanding  i think is  because  the  component is not yet render . So to cut  it short , Please can someone help  me out   , please  . Thanks  in advance .

js code

```
var dropdown = document.querySelector('.modal');
dropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  dropdown.classList.toggle('is-active');
});
```

error i get

```
    TypeError: dropdown is null
./src/modules/Restaurants/utils/main.js
C:/Users/user/Desktop/fungry/fungry/src/modules/Restaurants/utils/main.js:2

  1 | var dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
> 2 | dropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  3 |   event.stopPropagation();
  4 |   dropdown.classList.toggle('is-active');
  5 | });
```

will be waiting  thanks alot

Comment: You need to show more of your code. Can you include your entire React component? `dropdown` is most likely `null` because it has not been rendered yet like you say, so trying to call `addEventListener` on it will give rise to your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be writing this code inside `componentDidMount` function of you reactjs class inside which the `.modal` element lies.

```
componentDidMount(){
    var dropdown = document.querySelector('.modal');
    dropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        dropdown.classList.toggle('is-active');
    });   
}
```

By the way you should be using `onClick` attribute of react instead of binding click function like this